# Visual Studio 2019: Auto Indent

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, editor, auto-indent

Apologies for the triviality of this problem - I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Suppose I have the following block:

```
int plus(int x, int y)
{
    int z = x + y;% Cursor is here
}
```

After pressing return, I want the cursor to land here:

```
int plus(int x, int y)
{
    int z = x + y;
    % Cursor is here
}
```

But right now, it's landing here:

```
int plus(int x, int y)
{
    int z = x + y;
% Cursor is here
}
```

How can I make the editor auto-indent to the beginning of the previous line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Tools -> Options -> Text editor -> C/C++-> Tabs -> Indenting:**Smart** in Visual Studio.